# UPDATE using 2 tables not working from batch

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update, spring-batch

I need to update a table using the sum of values from a column of another table.

I'm using an Oracle database.

I have the following query :

```
UPDATE EFFET_COMMERCE 
SET EFFET_COMMERCE.CI21_ENCOF7 = (SELECT SUM(EFFET_COMMERCE_23_TMP.CI23_CUMTCR) FROM 
EFFET_COMMERCE_23_TMP WHERE EFFET_COMMERCE.CI2X_IDCONT = EFFET_COMMERCE_23_TMP.CI2X_IDCONT)
WHERE EFFET_COMMERCE.CI21_CDPRRT = '036993' 
AND EXISTS (SELECT SUM(EFFET_COMMERCE_23_TMP.CI23_CUMTCR) FROM
EFFET_COMMERCE_23_TMP WHERE EFFET_COMMERCE.CI2X_IDCONT = EFFET_COMMERCE_23_TMP.CI2X_IDCONT)
```

So I need to update the `CI21_ENCOF7` column from the `EFFET_COMMERCE` table where the `CI21_CDPRRT` is `'036993'` with the sum of the `CI23_CUMTCR` values of the `EFFET_COMMERCE_23_TMP` which have the same `CI2X_IDCONT`.

On SQLDeveloper, this query seems to work fine.
But When I'm using it in a Spring Batch, I'm getting the error :

> GRAVE: Encountered an error executing step injectionDesDonnees in job effetCommercialeBeanJob
>   org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [
>
> insert into EFFET_COMMERCE(CI10_DATRAI,CI2X_IDCGIC,CI2X_IDCONT,CI20_CDDV,CI21_CDPRRT,CI21_CDEPR3,CI21_DACRR7,CI21_DAFEPN,CI21_DADAU8,CI21_DAFNAU,CI21_MTAUTN,CI21_DADTAP,CI21_DAFIAB,CI21_MTAUTP,CI21_ENCOF7,CI21_DAECPN,CI21_STCOLE)
>   values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
>                 UPDATE EFFET_COMMERCE SET EFFET_COMMERCE.CI21_ENCOF7 = (SELECT SUM(EFFET_COMMERCE_23_TMP.CI23_CUMTCR) FROM
>   EFFET_COMMERCE_23_TMP WHERE EFFET_COMMERCE.CI2X_IDCONT =
>   EFFET_COMMERCE_23_TMP.CI2X_IDCONT) WHERE EFFET_COMMERCE.CI21_CDPRRT =
>   '036993' AND EXISTS (SELECT SUM(EFFET_COMMERCE_23_TMP.CI23_CUMTCR)
>   FROM EFFET_COMMERCE_23_TMP WHERE EFFET_COMMERCE.CI2X_IDCONT =
>   EFFET_COMMERCE_23_TMP.CI2X_IDCONT)
>                         ]; nested exception is java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-00933: la commande SQL ne se termine pas correctement

(Sql command doesnt' end properly)

Any idea what could be wrong ?

**EDIT :**
Here is the bean from the job-report.xml :

```
<bean id="insertItemWriter"
    class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcBatchItemWriter">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="sql">
        <value>
        <![CDATA[
            insert into EFFET_COMMERCE(CI10_DATRAI,CI2X_IDCGIC,CI2X_IDCONT,CI20_CDDV,CI21_CDPRRT,CI21_CDEPR3,CI21_DACRR7,CI21_DAFEPN,CI21_DADAU8,CI21_DAFNAU,CI21_MTAUTN,CI21_DADTAP,CI21_DAFIAB,CI21_MTAUTP,CI21_ENCOF7,CI21_DAECPN,CI21_STCOLE) values (:CI10_DATRAI, :CI2X_IDCGIC, :CI2X_IDCONT, :CI20_CDDV, :CI21_CDPRRT, :CI21_CDEPR3, :CI21_DACRR7, :CI21_DAFEPN, :CI21_DADAU8, :CI21_DAFNAU, :CI21_MTAUTN, :CI21_DADTAP, :CI21_DAFIAB, :CI21_MTAUTP, :CI21_ENCOF7, :CI21_DAECPN, :CI21_STCOLE);
            UPDATE EFFET_COMMERCE SET EFFET_COMMERCE.CI21_ENCOF7 = (SELECT SUM(EFFET_COMMERCE_23_TMP.CI23_CUMTCR) FROM EFFET_COMMERCE_23_TMP WHERE EFFET_COMMERCE.CI2X_IDCONT = EFFET_COMMERCE_23_TMP.CI2X_IDCONT) WHERE EFFET_COMMERCE.CI21_CDPRRT = '036993' AND EXISTS (SELECT SUM(EFFET_COMMERCE_23_TMP.CI23_CUMTCR) FROM EFFET_COMMERCE_23_TMP WHERE EFFET_COMMERCE.CI2X_IDCONT = EFFET_COMMERCE_23_TMP.CI2X_IDCONT);
        ]]>
        </value>
    </property>
    <!-- It will take care matching between object property and sql name parameter -->
    <property name="itemSqlParameterSourceProvider">
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

The compositeWriter bean from the the job-report.xml :

```
 <bean id="compositeWriter" class="com.socgen.cie.config.CompositeWriter" scope="step">
    <property name="datRaiP" value="#{jobParameters['datRaiP']}" />
    <property name="delegate1" ref="insert_20_ItemWriter" />
    <property name="delegate2" ref="insert_21_ItemWriter" />
    <property name="delegate3" ref="insert_23_ItemWriter" />
 </bean>
```

And the compositeWriter java class :

```
public class CompositeWriter implements ItemWriter<EffetCommercialeBean> {

    ItemWriter<EffetCommercialeBean> itemWriter1;
    ItemWriter<EffetCommercialeBean> itemWriter2;
    ItemWriter<EffetCommercialeBean> itemWriter3;
    private Date datRaiP;


     public void write(List<? extends EffetCommercialeBean> items) throws Exception {
        List<EffetCommercialeBean> inserts_20 = new ArrayList<EffetCommercialeBean>();
        List<EffetCommercialeBean> inserts_21 = new ArrayList<EffetCommercialeBean>();
        List<EffetCommercialeBean> inserts_23 = new ArrayList<EffetCommercialeBean>();
        Date date = getDatRaiP();
        for(EffetCommercialeBean re : items) {
//          if(re.getCI10_DATRAI()!=null){
//              date = dateFinDuMois(re.getCI10_DATRAI());
//          }
            re.setCI10_DATRAI(date);
            if("20".equals(re.getPattern())) {
                inserts_20.add(re);
            }
            if("21".equals(re.getPattern())) {
                inserts_21.add(re);
            }
            if("23".equals(re.getPattern())) {
                inserts_23.add(re);
            }
        }
        itemWriter1.write(inserts_20);
        itemWriter2.write(inserts_21);
        itemWriter3.write(inserts_23);
    }

    public void setDelegate1(ItemWriter<EffetCommercialeBean> itemWriter){
        this.itemWriter1 = itemWriter;
    }

    public void setDelegate2(ItemWriter<EffetCommercialeBean> itemWriter) {
        this.itemWriter2 = itemWriter;
    }

    public void setDelegate3(ItemWriter<EffetCommercialeBean> itemWriter) {
        this.itemWriter3 = itemWriter;
    }

    public Date getDatRaiP() {
        return datRaiP;
    }

    public void setDatRaiP(Date datRaiP) {
        this.datRaiP = datRaiP;
    }

}
```

Comment: You have used a not correct Spring method to perform the update. Post your Java code. The interpreter convert your SQL statement as INSERT INTO

Comment: Just edited the post, now I'm guessing I need to create a specific bean in the `job-report.xml` for the update ? I guess I will need to have a compositeUpdater java class as well ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, since I wanted to execute the `UPDATE` lastly, I ended up doing it after the job execution, since I don't know anything about spring-batch, this was the simpler solution for me :

```
execution = jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParameters(jobParametersMap));

                DataSource datasource = (DataSource) context.getBean("dataSource");
                Connection conn = datasource.getConnection();
                PreparedStatement query = conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE EFFET_COMMERCE SET EFFET_COMMERCE.CI21_ENCOF7 = (SELECT SUM(EFFET_COMMERCE_23_TMP.CI23_CUMTCR) FROM EFFET_COMMERCE_23_TMP WHERE EFFET_COMMERCE.CI2X_IDCONT = EFFET_COMMERCE_23_TMP.CI2X_IDCONT) WHERE EFFET_COMMERCE.CI21_CDPRRT = '036993' AND EXISTS (SELECT SUM(EFFET_COMMERCE_23_TMP.CI23_CUMTCR) FROM EFFET_COMMERCE_23_TMP WHERE EFFET_COMMERCE.CI2X_IDCONT = EFFET_COMMERCE_23_TMP.CI2X_IDCONT)");
                query.executeQuery();
```